# How to efficiently iterate over a very large list in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a `sample` data frame below:

| firstname | middlename | lastname | id | gender | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James |  | Smith | 36636 | M | 3000 |
| Michael | Rose |  | 40288 | M | 4000 |
| Robert |  | Williams | 42114 | M | 4000 |
| Maria | Anne | Jones | 39192 | F | 4000 |
| Jen | Mary | Brown |  | F | -1 |

---

Now I want to convert this into a `JSON` list like the below:

```
[{'firstname': 'James', 'middlename': '', 'lastname': 'Smith', 'id': '36636', 'gender': 'M', 'salary': 3000}, {'firstname': 'Michael', 'middlename': 'Rose', 'lastname': '', 'id': '40288', 'gender': 'M', 'salary': 4000}, {'firstname': 'Robert', 'middlename': '', 'lastname': 'Williams', 'id': '42114', 'gender': 'M', 'salary': 4000}, {'firstname': 'Maria', 'middlename': 'Anne', 'lastname': 'Jones', 'id': '39192', 'gender': 'F', 'salary': 4000}, {'firstname': 'Jen', 'middlename': 'Mary', 'lastname': 'Brown', 'id': '', 'gender': 'F', 'salary': -1}]
```

and I did that using the below code:

```
result = json.loads((df.toPandas().to_json(orient="records")))
```

Now what I want to do is, I want to send the `JSON` records one by one and hit the `API`. I can't send all the records at once and there are `millions` of records to be sent. So, how do I segregate these records using `Map()` or some other way so that it would work in a distributed fashion? It works well when I iterate a `for loop` on this list but takes time. So wanted to implement the most efficient way for this use case. The for loop code is as below:

```
for i in result_json:
            try:
                token = get_token(tokenUrl, tokenBody)
                custRequestBody = {
                            "Token": token,
                            "CustomerName": "",
                            "Object": "",
                            "Data": [i]
                }
                
                #print("::::Customer Request Body::::::")
                #print(custRequestBody)
                response = call_to_cust_bulk_api(apiUrl, custRequestBody)
                output = {
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "",
                    "X-Content-Type-Options": "",
                    "X-XSS-Protection": "",
                    "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
                    "Strict-Transport-Security": ""
                    },
                "body": {
                    "Response code": 200,
                    "ResponseMessage": response
                }
                }
```

Here, the `result_json` is already converted to the `JSON` list of records:

Comment: Can you share the for loop code you have, since that's the loop you're trying to rewrite and optimize?

Comment: I have added it. Please refer the post

Comment: Thanks, much better! But I think you forgot to paste the results at the end of your question.

Comment: I get a success response at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform operation row-wise on your df using a udf (user defined function).
Spark will run this function on all executors in a distributed fashion

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

# Your custom function you want to run in pyspark
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def parse_and_post(*args):
    print(args, type(args)) # args is of type typle
    # Convert the args tuple to json
    # Send the json to API
    # Return a Status value based on API success of failure
    """if success:
        return 200
    else
        return -1"""

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "John Doe", 21), (2, "Simple", 33)], ("id", "name", "age"))

# Apply the UDF to your Dataframe (called "df")
new_df = df.withColumn("post_status", parse_and_post( *[df[x] for x in df.columns] ))
```

**Note**

You might be tempted to call `collect()` function on your df and then iterate on rows but it will load all the data into the driver. Which beats the purpose of distributed computation.

Also the function will not be executed until you use/show the new_df since spark's lazy evaluation.

Read more about udf [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html)

Comment: Okay, let me try this. Looks good to me though.

Comment: The response is in the format of `JSON`. So what should be the return type? string?

Comment: I'm only storing the status code from response(int) in example. But if you want to store the complete response then you can use ``StringType()`` as your return type and inside the function convert the response json to string before return.

Comment: In case you require to store the response as a Struct you can refer to the page here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.StructType.html

Comment: I tried `result = json.loads((args.to_json(orient="records")))` and it gives me `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_json'` error

Comment: Yes, a tuple has no to_json method. You will have to write some python code to convert this into the desired json format.

Comment: Ok, let me check that.

Comment: Your tuple is actually printing the column names and if I try to access the value by using [0] it gives an error. Maybe something needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for this trick, man. It helped me to solve the problem